# How to close modal box after successful submit and open second modal conditionally on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to close form modal after successfully submit form and show another modal box after all error clear

When the form is submitted and the value of a html select list on the form has changed, then the conditional js confirmation pop up will display. The user must click the OK button on the js confirmation pop up for the form submission to proceed.

Or else if the html select list has not changed the js confirmation pop up will not display and the form will submit.

these are my codes:

```js
 $('#infoForm').bootstrapValidator({
//        live: 'disabled',
        message: 'This value is not valid',
      
        fields: {
            sName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
     stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
            sfName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Father name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
     stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The Father name must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The Father name can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            }
          
        }
    });
```

```html
<!--First modal Box-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Modal Box</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
  
     <form role="form" name="infoForm" id="infoForm" method="POST" action=""> 
    <div class="form-group">    
    <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" name="sName" id="sName" />
 </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Father Name" name="sfName" /></div>  
             <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit"  name="Submit1" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal" >Submit</button></div>
    </form>

 </div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
 </div>
    </div> 
  </div><!--end First modal Box-->
      <!-- second modal box -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">second modal box</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
   <p>Your Information successfully submit</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <!--  end second modal box-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Closing event of the modal box to check if it was succesful and open the new modal